# Smoothness of the Witt vectors ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a smooth $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra (or, more generally, $k$- where $k$ is a perfect field of char $p$). Consider the Witt vectors ring $W_n (A)$. Is this algebra smooth over $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ ($W_n(k)$ resp.)?

Comment: I'm interested in this question, but the presentation here is a little lacking right now- what have you tried, how did this come up, etc. One (maybe bad? idk, just spitballing) idea to start attacking it would be to check if $W_n(A)$ can be given by a tensor product - if you could show that $W_n(A) = W_n(k)\otimes_k A$, then this ought to do it by the fact that a base change of a smooth morphism is smooth, right?

Comment: @KReiser Unfortunately, that strategy doesn't work: we have a canonical map $W_n(k)\to k,$ but not the other way around (at least not a map of rings). So, the tensor product you've written down doesn't exist.

Comment: @Stahl well, I did say it might be a bad idea. Thanks for pointing out the flaw explicitly.

Comment: Doesn't the question come down to flatness since smoothness can be checked over closed fibers?

Comment: This doesn't imply quite what you want, but Theorem 2.4 in van der Kallen's "[Descent for the -theory of polynomial rings](www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002431580)" proves that if $B/A$ is étale, then $W_n(B)$ is étale over $W_n(A)$ for all $n$ (in the paper, $W_n$ refers to the big Witt vectors, but I assume that you can deduce the same result for $p$-typical Witt vectors).

Comment: Another remark which doesn't quite answer your question: if $A$ is a smooth algebra over a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p,$ then $W(A)$ is flat over $W(k)$: 6.20 of Hazewinkel's "[Witt Vectors: Part I](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0804/0804.3888.pdf)" proves that $W(k)$ is a DVR. Moreover, $W(A)$ is an integral domain if $A$ is, so that $W(A)$ is torsion-free over $W(k),$ hence flat. I'm not sure if you can pass from this statement to the corresponding one for $W_n$ without additional assumptions on $A.$ For example, for general $A$ it isn't true that $W_n(A) = W(A)/p^n.$

Comment: Thank you all. I think now that the answer is no. As far as I understand, a smooth algebra over a field is reduced (does it work in char p?). Now take $W_2 \mathbb{F}_p [x]$ and an element $Vx$. Note that $(Vx)^p =p^p x = 0$, since $FV=p$, so $Vx$ is a nilpotent element.

Comment: It is true that a smooth algebra over a field is always reduced, but once you take $W_n$ you're looking at smoothness over something generally non-reduced. If you take $W_2(\Bbb{F}_p)\cong\Bbb{Z}/p^2,$ there are smooth algebras over this ring which are non-reduced (e.g., itself).

Comment: @Asvin My previous comment was a little confusing. In general, you need to be careful with your statement that smoothness can be checked on closed fibers: to show that $f : X\to S$ is smooth, it's not enough in general to check that $f_s : X_s\to s$ is smooth for all closed points $s\in S,$ nor is it enough to check that $f : X\to S$ is smooth at all closed points of $X$ -- you can have schemes without any closed points, after all! However, it is true with some assumptions, which are verified in this setting (e.g., because everything is affine).

Comment: Well, let me be more precise then: Suppose we have a noetherian map of schemes $X \to S$. Then, being smooth is equivalent to being flat and each geometric fiber $X_s$ being smooth for $s$ a closed point of $S$. In our case, all the assumptions except flatness seem to be automatic.

Comment: @Stahl Right. That was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, only an extended comment with some partial progress. Throughout, let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p,$ and let $A$ be a smooth $k$-algebra.

**Claim:** It is enough to prove (or disprove) the result in the case where $A = k[x_1,\dots, x_d].$

**Proof:** First, recall that a morphism of schemes $f : X\to S$ is smooth if and only if for all $x\in X,$ and for all affine opens $V\ni f(x),$ there exists an affine open neighborhood $U$ of $x,$ an integer $d\geq 0,$ and an étale morphism $\pi : U\to\Bbb{A}^d_V$ such that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @<<< U @>\pi >> \Bbb{A}^d_V\\
@VfVV @V\left.f\right|_U VV @VVV\\
Y @<<< V @>\operatorname{id}_{V} >> V\\
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, where $\Bbb{A}^d_V\to V$ is the canonical map ([Stacks Project, tag 054L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/054L)).

Recall also that $W_{n}(A)\to A$ is a surjection with nilpotent kernel for any $n.$ In particular, $\operatorname{Spec}A\to\operatorname{Spec} W_n(A)$ is a homeomorphism. (See section 3 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.11130.pdf) for the statements.)

Now, since $A$ is smooth, for any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A,$ there exists $f\not\in\mathfrak{p}$ such that we have a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> A_f @<<< k[x_1,\dots, x_d]\\
@AAA @AAA @AAA\\
k @>\operatorname{id}>> k@<\operatorname{id}<< k\\
\end{CD}
$$
with $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to A$ étale.

Now, apply $W_n$ to the diagram above. We obtain
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
W_n(A) @>>> W_n(A_f) @<<< W_n(k[x_1,\dots, x_d])\\
@AAA @AAA @AAA\\
W_n(k) @>\operatorname{id}>> W_n(k)@<\operatorname{id}<< W_n(k)\\
\end{CD}
$$

By theorem 2.4 in van der Kallen's "[Descent for the -theory of polynomial rings](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002431580)," $W_n(k[x_1,\dots, x_d])\to W_n(A_f)$ is étale. Moreover, since $\operatorname{Spec} W_n(A)\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ is a homeomorphism, $\operatorname{Spec}W_n(A_f)$ is an affine open subset of $\operatorname{Spec} W_n(A).$

Let $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq W_n(A)$ be prime. Then there is a unique prime $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ lying under $\mathfrak{q},$ and to prove smoothness of $W_n(k)\to W_n(A)$ at $\mathfrak{q},$ it suffices to prove that
$$W_n(k)\to W_n(k[x_1,\dots, x_d])\to W_n(A_f)$$
is smooth for some $f\in A,$ $f\not\in\mathfrak{p}.$ As there exists such an $f$ for any $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ with $W_n(k[x_1,\dots, x_d])\to W_n(A_f)$ étale by smoothness of $k\to A,$ it is enough to prove that $W_n(k)\to W_n(k[x_1,\dots, x_d])$ is smooth.

Comment: That's nice. Nevertheless, I think that $W_2 \mathbb{F}_p [x]$ is not smooth over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ by the following reason. If it is smooth, then it is formally smooth. Then we also can take $\mathbb{Z}/p^2 [x]$ which is smooth over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ and by formally smoothness we get a map from one to another. I think that it should be an isomorphism by formal reasons but it is not.